# Self-hosted VPN service doesn't work stably

Tags: networking, vpn, webserver

I recently got a VPS to use as VPN-server which I connect with AmneziaVPN as a desktop client.

Yesterday everything seemed to work, but today it seems like something is wrong. For example, when
accessing https://medium.com thru VPN:

- Firefox Browser: returns "Secure Connection Failed" (like VPN is not working at all. This site is blocked from my original IP)
- Chrome Browser: works fine!

To be sure that it's not only a browser problem, I tried to access that site using curl on my local machine:

- `curl -is https://medium.com` returns nothing!
- However `curl -is https://medium.com` on VPN host machine has response with code 200.

Also, I checked my recognized IP-address when I connected to the VPN. It is right (IP of my VPN-host machine).

So what steps do I need to take at this stage to understand what the problem is? How can I test operability of my VPN-connection?

**UPD**

I checked AmneziaVPN logs, so it contains some warnings, but I'm not sure it's valueable:

```
    Line   1: 2023-06-04 08:52:04 warning libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
    Line   2: 2023-06-04 08:52:04 warning qrc:/ui/qml/Pages/Protocols/PageProtoTorWebSite.qml:30: ReferenceError: pb_save is not defined
    Line   3: 2023-06-04 08:52:04 debug Warning: Pages components are not ready
    Line   4: 2023-06-04 08:52:04 warning qrc:/ui/qml/Pages/PageQrDecoderIos.qml:27:5: QML Connections: Detected function "onStartDecode" in Connections element. This is probably intended to be a signal handler but no signal of the target matches the name.
    Line   5: 2023-06-04 08:52:04 warning qrc:/ui/qml/Pages/PageQrDecoderIos.qml:27:5: QML Connections: Detected function "onStopDecode" in Connections element. This is probably intended to be a signal handler but no signal of the target matches the name.
    Line   6: 2023-06-04 08:52:04 warning qrc:/ui/qml/Pages/PageQrDecoderIos.qml:28: ReferenceError: nil is not defined
    Line   7: 2023-06-04 08:52:05 warning QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
    Line  71: 2023-06-04 08:52:13 debug stderr Warning: `/opt/amnezia/wireguard/wg0.conf' is world accessible
```

Comment: Make sure to use verbose output from CURL. Also, I recommend using (or at least trying) the original WireGuard Windows client. I use it every day and have not encountered any problems with it.